# Angular ngrepeat multiple items in an array using directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to list multiple items with different info(song name, artist name, album name, album image). These information are in an array in an angular directive and I need to inject them into separate templateUrl using element injection. This is the directive

```
 app.directive('songList', function($filter) {
   return {
     restrict: 'E',
     templateUrl: $filter('baseUrl')("/content/mobile/app/views/addmusic/songList.html"),
     controller: function($scope, $timeout) {
       $scope.loadMoreSongs = function() {
         $scope.busy = true;
         $timeout(function() {
           $scope.offset += $scope.pageSize;
           if ($scope.offset > $scope.songs.length)
             $scope.offset = $scope.songs.length;
           $scope.busy = false;
         }, 300);
       };

       $scope.songs = [{
         "id": 1,
         "songName": "Children of the Sea",
         "artistName": "Black         Sabbath",
         "albumName": "Heaven and Hell",
         "thumbnailUrl": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f8/Black_Sabbath_Heaven_and_Hell.jpg"
       }, {
         "id": 2,
         "songName": "Turbo Lover",
         "artistName": "Judas Priest",
         "albumName": "Turbo Lover",
         "thumbnailUrl": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/8a/Judas_Priest_Turbo.jpg"
       }, {
         "id": 3,
         "songName": "High Hopes",
         "artistName": "Pink Floyd",
         "albumName": "Divison Bell",
         "thumbnailUrl": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/el/9/96/Pink_floyd_the_division_bell_front.jpg"
       }, {
         "id": 4,
         "songName": "When a Blind Man Cries",
         "artistName": "Deep Purple",
         "albumName": "Machine Head",
         "thumbnailUrl": "http://www.inthestudio.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/deep_purple_machine_head_640x640.jpg"
       }, {
         "id": 5,
         "songName": "Amamos La Vida",
         "artistName": "Accept",
         "albumName": "Objection Overruled",
         "thumbnailUrl": "https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7051/6982758045_167210f89e.jpg"
       }];
     },
     controllerAs: 'song'
   }
 });
```

This is the templateUrl (songListItem.html) where one song is shown:

```
<li class="media">
  <a ng-href="#">
    <div class="song-names-container">
      <div class="img-container media-left">
        <img class="media-object img-frame" src="{{song.thumbnailUrl}}" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="media-body">
        <h3><strong>{{song.songName}}</strong></h3>
        <div>
          <p>{{song.artistName}} - {{song.albumName}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

And this is the main html page (songList.html) where the ngrepeat is suposed to get in action and display the list of songs:

```
<div class="add-music-form">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search over 15 million songs..." />
  </div>
  <div class="song-names-title">
    <p>Songs</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <ul class="media-list">
      <song-list-item ng-repeat="song in songs"></song-list-item>
    </ul>
    <div class="more-songs"></div>
    <div class="album-names-title"></div>
    <div class="album-names"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? From the code you have added, you are not using the `songListItem.html` at all.

Comment: songListItem.html is a template that renders in song-list-item tag and it needs to repeat with each item in array. What do you mean by not using it at all ?

Comment: You do not reference the template anywhere in your code and I don't see how you have tried to achieve what you want by yourself. StackOverflow is not for others to solve your programming tasks, but to help you with problems you encounter while solving them yourself.

Comment: I think there's just a typo, and songList.html in the directive should be songListItem.html

Comment: @muencdo When I dont use ng-repeat templete songListItem renders fine, but it doesnt load items form array. That is the problem: how to add items from the array to the page. I'm not asking you to solve the problem for me, just a suggestion where and what I should look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I didn't place the songList directive anywhere. I added the index.html file, included it there.

```html
<div class="musicMain" ng-controller="BasicAppCtrl">
    <song-list></song-list>
</div>
```

```html
<ul class="media-list">
           <song-list-item data-model="song" ng-repeat="song in songs"></song-list-item>
</ul>
```

And that is that.

Answer (score 0):

`song` is like an instance variable, so just because it's named the same thing in the template and in the ng-repeat, doesn't mean they're connected.

You need to modify your directive so it accepts an attribute, and then pass song to that attribute, which I think would look something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="song in songs">
    <song-list-item song-data={{song}}></song-list-item>
</div>
```